# How to draw a rectangle in MathJax?

Tags: latex, mathjax

How can I draw a rectangle in MathJax?

width = 5, length = 10 (units = mm)

thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `\Rule{10mm}{5mm}{0mm}` to get a black rectangle with the given size.  Use `\color{red}{\Rule{10mm}{5mm}{0mm}}` to get a red rectangle.

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/mathjax@2/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS_CHTML"></script>

<p>
Black rectangle: \(\Rule{10mm}{5mm}{0mm}\)
</p>

<p>
Red rectangle: \(\color{red}{\Rule{10mm}{5mm}{0mm}}\)
</p>
```